# Using a variable passed in PHP PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, variables, pdo

Whith help from a Question I ask for some Minutes I get from this code:

```
$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT groupid  FROM user_groups WHERE userid=?");
$sth->execute(array($uid));
$sth->execute();

$results = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
$results = implode(",",$resultas);
echo $results;
```

A Output like this: 11,13. Thanks for your Help:)

Now I want to use this variable in another pdo-Query and I try this:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM menu WHERE gruppe=0 OR gruppe in (?'
    . ') ORDER BY reihe, parentId, name ');
$stmt->execute(array($results));
```

But there is no result... but wehen I try this

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM menu WHERE gruppe=0 OR gruppe in (11,13'
    . ') ORDER BY reihe, parentId, name ');
$stmt->execute();
```

Isn't this the same? Can you pleas give me another hint for this?

Comment: Note that it is only a duplicate if you need to do it in 2 separate queries. I voted to close as it was an unreadable mess in the beginning :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should do this in one query as you would need to bind all values individually otherwise:

```
SELECT * FROM menu
  WHERE gruppe=0 OR gruppe IN (SELECT groupid FROM user_groups WHERE userid=?)
  ORDER BY reihe, parentId, name
```

Comment: `gruppe` is a reserved word. lol *grin*

Comment: @Fred-ii- A little bit of German never hurts :)

Comment: @Rizier123 Si signore RR

Comment: @Rizier123 You've obviously never had to learn it ;-)